# How to use splice method to delete items within JSON

Tags: javascript, web

How do i delete an items from JSON array which is given in the code below.

```
[{"name":"John","city":"New York"},{"name":"abe","city":"New York"},{"name":"mathew","city":"New York"}]
```

Comment: Image does not exist and you should not post code in an image.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @ecg8 - close, but this question is about removing an entry in an array, not a property from an object.  I'm sure there's another duplicate out there for that particular case as well, though.

Comment: I would say this is the more likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: @Alexander Nied, you are probably right. When I flagged it the image was still unavailable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript splice function

```
YourArray.splice(0, 1);
```

where `0` will be the key which need to be removed and `1` will be the number of items which need to be removed from that key.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = localStorage.getItem("tasks"); // get the tasks from localstorage
a = JSON.parse(a); // convert from string to array
a.splice(0,1); // splice the array -> 0 = index of item to be removed, 1 = no of items to be removed
localStorage.setItem("tasks",JSON.stringify(a)); // set the updated task list in localstorage
```